# Cant compress files with django-pipeline and YUI

Tags: django, yui-compressor, django-compressor

When I run **python manage.py collectstatic**, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/fceruti/Development/Arriendas.cl/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/fceruti/Development/xxxxx/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/fceruti/Development/xxxxx/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Users/fceruti/Development/xxxxx/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/fceruti/Development/xxxxx/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/Users/fceruti/Development/xxxxx/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 163, in handle_noargs
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/Users/fceruti/Development/xxxxx/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 119, in collect
    dry_run=self.dry_run)
  File "/Users/fceruti/Development/xxxxx/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipeline/storage.py", line 30, in post_process
    packager.pack_stylesheets(package)
  File "/Users/fceruti/Development/xxxxx/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipeline/packager.py", line 90, in pack_stylesheets
    variant=package.variant, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/fceruti/Development/xxxxx/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipeline/packager.py", line 100, in pack
    content = compress(paths, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/fceruti/Development/xxxxx/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipeline/compressors/__init__.py", line 72, in compress_css
    css = self.concatenate_and_rewrite(paths, output_filename, variant)
  File "/Users/fceruti/Development/Arriendas.cl/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipeline/compressors/__init__.py", line 135, in concatenate_and_rewrite
    content = self.read_file(path)
  File "/Users/fceruti/Development/xxxxx/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipeline/compressors/__init__.py", line 208, in read_file
    file = default_storage.open(path, 'rb')
  File "/Users/fceruti/Development/xxxxx/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 33, in open
    return self._open(name, mode)
  File "/Users/fceruti/Development/xxxxx/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipeline/storage.py", line 114, in _open
    storage = self.find_storage(name)
  File "/Users/fceruti/Development/xxxxx/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipeline/storage.py", line 111, in find_storage
    raise ValueError("The file '%s' could not be found with %r." % (name, self))
ValueError: The file 'css/960_24_col.css' could not be found with <pipeline.storage.PipelineFinderStorage object at 0x101da4d50>.
```

When I run **python manage.py findstatic css/960_24_col.css**, I get

```
Found 'css/960_24_col.css' here:
  /Users/fceruti/Development/xxxxxxx/Arriendas/static/css/960_24_col.css
```

My settings are:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('css', os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'css')),
    ('img', os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'img')),
    ('js', os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'js')),
    ('fonts', os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'fonts')),
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
PIPELINE = True
PIPELINE_CSS = {
    'app': {
        'source_filenames': (
            'css/960_24_col.css',
            'css/base.scss',
        ),
        'output_filename': 'css/app.css',
        'extra_context': {
            'media': 'screen,projection',
        },
    },
}
PIPELINE_CSS_COMPRESSOR = 'pipeline.compressors.yui.YUICompressor'
PIPELINE_JS_COMPRESSOR = 'pipeline.compressors.yui.YUICompressor'
PIPELINE_YUI_CSS_ARGUMENTS = ''
PIPELINE_YUI_JS_ARGUMENTS = ''
PIPELINE_YUI_BINARY = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'libs/yuicompressor-2.4.7/build/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar')

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineCachedStorage'
PIPELINE_SASS_BINARY = '/usr/bin/sass'
```

When I add

```
PIPELINE_COMPILERS = (
    'pipeline.compilers.sass.SASSCompiler',
)
```

And run the webpage, I get:

```
Exception Type: CompilerError
Exception Value:    
Unable to apply SASSCompiler compiler
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

The softwares I'm using are:

- Sass 3.1.19 (Brainy Betty)
- YUI compressor 2.4.7
- django-pipeline==1.2.11
- Django 1.4

Comment: It doesn't seem to be combining them with your STATIC_ROOT. Have you tried just using the `PipelineStorage` instead of `PipelineCachedStorage`? Also try `PipelineFinderStorage` as it says its for the dev server.

Comment: I tried that, but it fails because collectstatic doesnt make the output files, and I get 404 errors

Comment: Can you add your staticfiles settings, the pipeline version you are using and also the complete traceback for CompilerError.  Thanks.

Comment: @cyberdelia ok, I just added those things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, You should not put the jar as `PIPELINE_YUI_BINARY`, but you should point to a script that call the jar with java (most of the time, it's bundle with it when packaged). It looks like this :

```
#!/bin/sh
java -jar "/path/to/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar" $@
```

Comment: could you give me a hint on where that script is, or how should I build it?

Comment: @fceruti I've added it to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think you want your STATICFILES_DIRS to look something like this:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = ('./static/')
```

If that doesn't work, try something like this.

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)[0: (os.path.dirname(__file__).rindex(os.sep + 'src' + os.sep))])
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static/' ))
```

(the idea is to set PROJECT_ROOT to the top level directory for your app)

The way you have it set up it will look in each of your sub directories for "css/960_24_col.css" In other words it will look for

- STATIC_ROOT/**css/css**/960_24_col.css
- STATIC_ROOT/img/css/960_24_col.css
- STATIC_ROOT/js/css/960_24_col.css
- STATIC_ROOT/fonts/css/960_24_col.css

And it won't find it, because the file is at

```
STATIC_ROOT/css/960_24_col.css
```

---

In general, STATICFILES_DIRS is a collection of /static/ directories that are contained in different apps. If yourApp includes myApp, and myApp has a static directory you'd put both yourApp's static dir and myApps static dir on the list. Collectstatic will combine them into STATIC_ROOT and then run Pipeline on that.